# What are the changes to be made to xampp for calling .net web services

Tags: web-services, drupal, xampp

I am working on Drupal 6 creating my own custom modules. Untill recently, i was able to call my .net web services from my php file. I do remember that i had searched a modification to be done in the xampp set up (i vaguely remember it to be php.ini). But my system crashed, and i needed to start all over again.I have my code for the modules intact; however the web services call just wont work.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://freeway.demo.lionbridge.com/vojo/FreewayAuth.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://freeway.demo.lionbridge.com/vojo/FreewayAuth.asmx?wsdl" in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalHome\sites\all\modules\freeway_module\freeway.admin.inc:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalHome\sites\all\modules\freeway_module\freeway.admin.inc(22): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://freeway...', Array) #1 [internal function]: send_for_translation(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalHome\includes\form.inc(377): call_user_func_array('send_for_transl...', Array) #3 [internal function]: drupal_retrieve_form('send_for_transl...', Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalHome\includes\form.inc(103): call_user_func_array('drupal_retrieve...', Array) #5 [internal function]: drupal_get_form('send_for_transl...') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalHome\includes\menu.inc(349): call_user_func_array('drupal_get_form', Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalHome\index.php(17): m in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalHome\sites\all\modules\freeway_module\freeway.admin.inc on line 22
```

This is the error it throws for the authentication web service login call.

This is the code

```
$LoginClient = new SoapClient("https://freeway.demo.lionbridge.com/vojo/FreewayAuth.asmx?wsdl", array("trace"=>1)); 
        $ServicesLink = new SoapClient("https://freeway.demo.lionbridge.com/vojo/Service.asmx?wsdl", array("trace"=>1));


          try{

          $arrResponse = $LoginClient->Logon(array ('Username'=>'username','Password'=>'password'));
          $ticket = ($arrResponse->LogonResult);
          $getSrcLang = $ServicesLink->GetSourceLanguages(array('Ticket'=>$ticket));
          $getDraftProjectIds = $ServicesLink->GetProjectSummariesList(array('Ticket'=>$ticket,'NumberOfProjects'=>100,'SortOrder'=>MostRecent,'ProjectStatusCode'=>'Draft'));

                        $array = array();
                        $arrayT = array();
                        $forTarLang = array();
                        $listOfProjects = array();

                        foreach($getSrcLang->GetSourceLanguagesResult->Languages->Language as $language)                
                        {                                       
                          $array[$language->ID] = $language->Description."_".$language->ID;                                 
                            $forTarLang[] = $language->ID;
                        }


                        foreach($getDraftProjectIds->GetProjectSummariesListResult->ProjectSummaries->ProjectSummary as $projectSummary)
                        {
                          $listOfProjects[$projectSummary->ID] = $projectSummary-> ID;
                        }

                                    $tarLang = array();                     

          }
              catch (SoapFault $exception){
              return $exception;
              }

                      try{

                      if (count($forTarLang)!=0){
                            $getTarLang = $ServicesLink->GetTargetLanguages(array('Ticket'=>$ticket,'SourceLanguageID'=>$forTarLang[0]));

                            foreach($getTarLang->GetTargetLanguagesResult->Languages->Language as $languageT)   
                                {                   
                                $arrayT[$languageT->ID] = $languageT->Description;                                                                  
                                }                               
                        }
                     } 
                      catch (SoapFault $exception1){
                       return $exception1;
                      }
```

Would like to know if any one has any tips regarding the same. Unfortunately i am trying to fing a solution which i had. Any help will be invaluable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is adding php_openssl.dll inside the ext folder.